# Surround-with template with resharper that formats the selection

Tags: resharper, resharper-6.0

I am trying to create a surround-with template with resharper that formats a selection like this

```
string foo = "A text with spaces";
```

into this:

```
string foo = Translate("ATextWithSpaces");
```

I want to select the "A text with spaces" myself, press the surround-with shortcut and just watch it happen!

I have a template that produces

```
string foo = Translate("A text with spaces")
```

...but that's not good enough for me. Any suggestions?

Comment: could you create a method that formatted your string as you want it (without spaces and camal-case), so your call would be `string foo = Translate(RemoveSpaces("A text with spaces"))` or include it in your `Translate` method?

Comment: Including it in my translate method would actually work. Creating such a method in code would not be that hard actually. Good thinking! However, I parse the .cs files for usages of Translate() for other reasons, and there it would be best to have the correct value directly. I guess I could use that same functionality there though...

Comment: Thinking about it for another few seconds, your approach has some other advantages. Seeing the value in code, as it was originally written is beneficial! What a difference a pair of new eyes have!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on my comment:

You could create a new method that formats your string as you want it, something like:

```
public string RemoveSpaces(string input)
{
    return new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB", false).TextInfo.ToTitleCase(input).Replace(" ", "");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're prepared to venture into ReSharper plug-in dev territory, this yields a very, very simple plug-in that would take minutes to implement. Basically, what you can do is make a context action that, when the caret is on a string literal, would take said literal, remove spaces (with `string.Replace`), then create a new expression using e.g., `CSharpElementFactory.CreateExpressionAsIs("Translate($1)", x)` where `x` is the modified literal.

If you're interested in doing this and need more info, feel free to contact me (skype: dmitri.nesteruk, email: dn at jetbrains dot com) with any questions you may have.